# Passing querystring to http endpoint with AWS_IAM auth (AWS API GATEWAY)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-api-gateway

I have a GET method with some querystring defined in AWS Api Gateway, this method is secured by AWS IAM auth.

When i make a request from postman using any querystring i get this message: **"The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method...**

However, if i remove the IAM auth it works.

Comment: hey found any solution i am facing same issue in asp.net4.0 c# code..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Mike for your prompt response.
It seems the problem rely with the mac version of postman, i tried again with the chrome version and works well.
I realize that this two version generate different signatures with the same AWS Access Key and Secret Key.

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue with Postman and my code as well. Strangely, Postman would return the error regardless of having query param or not. My app would only return an error when I include the query string. What did you do to solve yours in your app?

Answer (score 0):

We've seen reports of Postman defaulting to setting a Content-Type header of "x-www-form-urlencoded".  This can prevent it from generating a correct signature in some cases. Try explicitly setting a Content-Type header of "application/json" in Postman.

If that doesn't work, please post details of your Postman request, but don't post that actual value of your AWS Access Key nor Secret Key.  Also, don't post the actual signature value.

Answer (score 0):

We've also seen that some version of Postman don't reset the authorization header after changing other aspects of the request.  In these cases you can delete the authorization header manually to force Postman to recreate it.